# After Laravel .htaccess root-implementation, script sources wont work

Tags: javascript, laravel, .htaccess

### I want a nicer URL, so I copied a `.htaccess` file into the root directory of my Laravel 7 project.

Everything works great. Only the script sources that I linked in the HTML code wont work:

`<script src="./../resources/folder/js/myscript.js"></script>`

> The requested URL could not be found on the server.

I've tried changing the path in many different ways, but I have no idea what the problem is. I also have no experience with `.htaccess` files.

Links like `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>` works fine.

My `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: You should link to asset files in your ... `public` folder, not the `resources` folder. Run `npm run dev` to compile your resources to public

Comment: At the moment its not possible to load `mdbootstrap` via webpack. So i must add it manually to the environment. Normally i would add all files via webpack (or Laravel-Mix).

Comment: ?? mdbootstrap can be installed via `npm`, or not? Anyway, if you can't, download the package and place the files inside your `public/css` and `public/js` folder

Comment: mdbootstrap can be installed via npm, but it doesn't work there. Therefore it has to be inserted manually. Your idea to move mdbootstrap to the public folder and use it from there worked. Thank you!